# Thoughts on unit test automation

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Assume you are testing an complex function or a complex store procedure. How do you perform the automation?

i had two options:

1. Baseline test:
   i prepare some input data, i run the test manually at first, then i get the output data. After check, i think the output data is correct. then i use the output data as "Baseline data".  In the later test, i compare the output data with the "Baseline data", if there is changes, they maybe bug or somethig else.
2. Tester implement the function or store procedure in another way. For testing, it compare the output from tester's function and the output from developer's function.

Option 1 is easier to be implemented in automation.
Option 2 is harder since the tester need to re-write the function.

is there any other options?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, unit tests probably shouldn't be testing whether the database returns the correct data.  There is just too much that could go wrong.  The database could be down, the user could kill the tests before you reset the baseline.  This is more of an integration test than unit test.

I typically use a mocked data access layer with mocked up data for testing.

see links [here](http://www.nileshgule.com/2010/04/use-nbuilder-to-generate-test-data.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244118/data-driven-unit-tests)

All of that said, when I *HAVE* to create unit tests that pull data from the database, I generally program my tests to update the database with test data, then I run my database calls / stored procs and test against that baseline.

Comment: i guess it is more of #1, except you create the baseline data only once and force it at the beginning of the test.